# How can I modify (add or delete some svg icons) on a .woff or .ttf file?

Tags: svg, truetype, woff, fontforge

I'm working on an app that I haven't coded. This app is using customs icons from an .woff file (or .ttf). I have never used this type of file before. I reach to open it with https://fontdrop.info/ and I can see the elements on the file. But I have to add some new icons. How can I do that?
I think that I have to :

- Create the new icon with a software (like fontforge?).
- Edit my .woff file to add my new icon.

Do you know some softwares like fontforge? Which one is the easiest to use?
How can I modify my current file with the new icon?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Something like Icomoon may do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that with Icomoon I can create a new .woff file with several customs svg but I can't add to an existing file woff another svg...
My woff file contains like 30 icons and I have to add five more.
I searched for a .woff to .svg converter and I found a lot but it always convert to an only one svg file which is seemingly empty...
It will be more convenient if I can have all the icons on svg format but I haven't.

Comment: @Petitemo: Try to convert your icon.woff font with [transfonter](https://transfonter.org) to a svg font file. You won't see any icons when opening it directly, since all icons are just glyphs definitions that are not placed anywhere as visible elements. The generated svg should work fine in icomoon app.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried to open the svg file with icomoon and it works. Thanks a lot!